# Octave - logsig transfer function

Tags: matlab, octave

Does Octave have a built-in logistic transfer function similar to Matlab's [logsig](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/logsig.html) function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe Octave does, but you can certainly create `logsig` outputs yourself.  The `logsig` transfer function (or the Log-Sigmoid function... or simply the [Sigmoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) function) is simply defined as:

```
a = 1 ./ (1 + exp(-n));
```

`n` would be the input values stored in a vector / matrix / etc.  As such, simply place your values into a matrix / vector into `n`, then use the above code to apply the `logsig` function to every value that is defined in `n`.

## Example

```
n = [0; 1; -0.5; 0.5];
a = 1 ./ (1 + exp(-n))

a =

    0.5000
    0.7311
    0.3775
    0.6225
```

Comparing this with MATLAB's `logsig` function, we get:

```
a2 = logsig(n)

a2 =

    0.5000
    0.7311
    0.3775
    0.6225
```

Comment: That was my initial solution as well, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't defining a function for an already included one. Thanks for the computation comparison that's great!

Comment: @aconkey - My pleasure!  I did scour the Octave docs before posting an answer btw.  I probably should have mentioned that in my answer.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

logsig is part of the nnet octave-forge package. http://sourceforge.net/p/octave/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/octave-forge/main/nnet/inst/logsig.m

If it's not in core Matlab (Neural Network Toolbox in this case) you should have a look at the corresponding octave-forge package. Unfortunally nnet is unmaintained.

The logsig.m linked is basically the same as rayrengs but also checks for finite.